# Custom php template file only for mobile

Tags: theme-development

Hey guys thanks in advance to all, 
I was wondering if there is way to run a costume php template file only for mobile?

case:  I'm using Woo commerce and I want to make a costum template for the single product page, is it possible to execute that template just for mobile via php / js or any other way ?

I don't want to tweak the main template via Css using `display: none` etc.

thanks to all,

update:

I'v tried this code but it seems to break ant tips:

```
<?php
    if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
      <?php wc_get_template( 'layouts/test.php' ); ?>
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to customize the look and feel with CSS? I personally prefer that; if you go with separate templates for mobile I would use a separate domain as well, otherwise you won't be able to use any HTML cache plugins.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply, first of all thank you. I want to edit it via php because I don't want to many `hidden` elements on the page as far as I understand this is not good practice.  thanks for the tip regarding separate domain and cache didn't' know that

Answer (score 0):

archive product page overwrite into your current active theme.
 More detail **[wp_is_mobile()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/)**

```
<?php
// archive product page


if( wp_is_mobile() )
{
    // your costume template path
}else{
    // Woocommerce defult archive page code put into else part
}

?>
```

Hope is work for you

Comment: Hey @Patel Jignesh thanks and sorry for the late reply. yes it does make things more clear for sure, just one question where this code needs to go inside `index.php` ?

Comment: Hey I'v tried your tip, but it seems not to work you can see the code I'v used in the update above cheers